# mysql polygon + point

Tags: mysql, polygon

Я пытаюсь получить записи из mysql по имеющейся области. Не могу понять в чем проблема в запросе. Вот как я пытаюсь это сделать:

`SELECT CONCAT('POINT(',lat,' ',lng,')') as pnt, if(Contains(GeomFromText('POLYGON((55.342165 31.733829, 58.118611 42.808047, 58.141857 43.643008, 57.721089 45.005313, 57.247739 46.016055, 56.574652 46.587344, 55.367202 46.543399, 54.327584 44.653751, 53.810645 42.676212, 53.575909 39.951602, 53.339857 34.546329, 53.758595 31.997501, 54.044068 31.601993, 55.065706 31.382266, 55.517091 32.436954))'),GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',lat,' ', lng,')'))), 'yes', 'no') as in_poly FROM coordinates`

В таблице координат у меня есть точки которые должны попасть в плоскость. Но мне кажется что у меня не создается плоскость.

Comment: Я попробовал получить тип, но получаю null:
`SELECT ST_GeometryType(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((55.795627 37.399341, 55.818056 37.53461, 55.817283 37
.652026, 55.80491 37.704898, 55.780151 37.76395, 55.760411 37.798282, 55.724775 37.829868, 55.717024
 37.813388, 55.715861 37.746783, 55.757313 37.400714, 55.764669 37.380801, 55.77783 37.373248, 55.789051
 37.386295, 55.796401 37.406207))')) as type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение заключается в следующем: в конец полученных с карты координат необходимо ставить первую пару координат. По моим соображениям это "замыкает" плоскость.

Вот верный запрос:

`SELECT CONCAT('POINT(',lat,' ',lng,')') as pnt, if(Contains(GeomFromText('POLYGON((55.342165 31.733829, 58.118611 42.808047, 58.141857 43.643008, 57.721089 45.005313, 57.247739 46.016055, 56.574652 46.587344, 55.367202 46.543399, 54.327584 44.653751, 53.810645 42.676212, 53.575909 39.951602, 53.339857 34.546329, 53.758595 31.997501, 54.044068 31.601993, 55.065706 31.382266, 55.517091 32.436954, 55.342165 31.733829))'),GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',lat,' ', lng,')'))), 'yes', 'no') as in_poly FROM coordinates`

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/224359)

Comment: @Виктор напишите пожалуйста чем Вас не устроил мой ответ.